# How can Boruto handle a Chōōdama Rasengan?

Tags: naruto, naruto-gaiden

We see that at the end of Boruto:Naruto the Movie,

> Boruto defeats the enemy by hitting him with what it seems a Chōōdama Rasengan (IMHO it looks larger than a Chōōdama Rasengan). I think Naruto infused some of his chakra in Boruto's jutsu to make it that big.

We see it took time for Jiraiya and Naruto to master the Rasengan, and Naruto was actually the only one to take it to the next level by adding his wind chakra (at the time).

So how can Boruto handle this large amount of chakra? Yes everyone says that Boruto can easily beat Naruto if you compare them at the same genin stage of their lives, but that doesn't mean Boruto is trained to manipulate such an insane amount of chakra. How was he able to pull it off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only strain Rasengan users show is from the chakra required to create it - It requires a LOT of chakra to create. Manipulating the chakra, while difficult to master, doesn't seem very draining. Even genin Naruto was able to spend entire days practicing the chakra manipulation part. Since we've seen Boruto make his own Rasengan, we know he understands the chakra manipulation part, so he can obviously handle using/attacking with it. He doesn't however have the completely bonkers reserve of Chakra that Naruto has, so he can't make the Giant Rasengan himself.

There's no reason to assume that the mechanics of the Rasengan change as it gets larger, so Boruto's own ability to manipulate chakra flow should be similarly applicable across all sizes of Rasengan.

I'd even wager that the manipulation part isn't particularly important, since we see Naruto give his friends Rasengans of their own to use during the Fourth Shinobi War, implying that it may be a completely self-sustaining jutsu so long as there is a chakra supply.

Comment: But shouldn't become a bit more difficult to manipulate this chakra as its "mass" -to give it a measurement unit- increases? Take bread dough for example, the larger it is the more difficult is to work with it.

Comment: He's not "manipulating" the bread though. He's already combined all the "ingredients" into his "dough", all his father did was add an insanely large amount of dough to his dough. Everything is done, he just needs to put it in the oven ((throw it in the bad guy's face))

Answer (score 2):

Let me quote these lines from [wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rasengan):

> The Rasengan does not require hand seals to perform. Once it is
>   formed, it also does not require any additional chakra to sustain it

Although it doesn't require any additional chakra to sustain it (so I guess once it is formed it can be used by another person, too), but that doesn't also mean that it will not be difficult; it will be difficult to handle that chakra and to perfectly balance it.

In case of Boruto's Rasengan:

> Though Boruto's Rasengan is initially much smaller, he subconsciously
>   applies wind-natured chakra to it, enabling him to hurl the
>   Rasengan across distances. While it loses its physical form shortly
>   after bring thrown, the wind and force continue on-course unseen,
>   tricking the opponent to let their guard down as sufficient damage is
>   inflicted when it makes contact.

At first, Boruto really tried hard to achieve this stage so there is no doubt that he won't be able to handle Rasengan. But there is one more point to note: Boruto subconsciously applies wind-natured chakra to his Rasengan which perfectly defines that he was able to create Rasengan with that much power.

At the end of the movie:

> Naruto is impressed that Boruto was able to learn the Rasengan and,
>   still unable to move, adds his own chakra to Boruto's Rasengan, making
>   it gigantic.

So Naruto simply added his own chakra to make that Rasengan much bigger. Since Boruto also learns how to perform Rasengan while training from Konohamaru Sarutobi after extensive practice then that's why he was able to handle Bigger Rasengan. (Note: that it was his own Rasengan but in bigger size than the usual one.)

Also in Boruto Uzumaki's [wikia page](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Boruto_Uzumaki), there is nothing mentioned about Choodama Rasengan (also in movie) in the Jutsu section, so according to the given information, we must accept the fact that it was not a Choodama Rasengan.

Comment: fyi Chōōdama Rasengan just stands for big ball rasengan, the question you linked has nothing to do with my question, since we're talking about different parts of the movie.

Comment: @JustDoIt I guess you are right. I might have accidently added that. I just edited it. But one thing you must note that in Boruto Uzumaki Wiki profile - where in jutsu section there is nothing mentioned about Choodama Rasengan(also in movie), so according to given information we must accept the fact that it was not a Choodama Rasengan

Comment: You can then edit what you've said in that comment, that applies more to the question than pointing out another scene that wasn't being discussed. I like your last comment much more than the paragraph that was edited out @LightYagami

Comment: the main issue with the giant rasengan is the chakra required to make it, not the ability to handle it. Jiriya only uses larger rasengans in Sage mode, where he can use Nature chakra instead of his own. Narutos first large rasengan against the Fake Itachi drained him heavily chakra wise, but in the end, he thrusted it himself similar to a regular rasengan.  It was exactly like when he gave the Giant rasengans to his friends in the War just before they defeated Juubi Obito, they cant use rasengan, but controling a hunk of chakra that is stable is probably not difficult.