# How does Vanishing Rasengan work?

Tags: naruto, boruto

Vanishing Rasengan is a miniature Rasengan which was originally developed by Boruto as seen in Boruto: Naruto the Movie. In that movie, when Boruto was trying to learn Rasengan in front of Sasuke, it was observed that his Rasengan usually vanishes into the air but the effect of Rasengan is still there.

How was Boruto able to make the Rasengan vanish? How does Vanishing Rasengan work?

Comment: Remember he also used that Rasengan while fighting at last scene where he aimed that Rasengan on the enemy hand (sorry but I don't know the name). So by that I don't think it was his mistake. May be he has some talent but unaware of that.

Comment: ya, he did do it agasint that enemy, and the vanishing rasengan acted exactly the same as when it was shown in front of sasuke. Boruto threw it, the visible chakra disappeared, but the force of the rasengan itself continued on in a shock wave like manner until it hit his arm (or the tree when it was with sasuke). The regular rasengan is not throw able for some reason, though rasen shuriken is, though naruto does not do so in his normal mode, indicating it requires something else.

Comment: @LightYagami You seem to have answered your own question here http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/30096/22449

Comment: It vanishes because the rasengan isn't fully formed, so it's not as stable as a regular rasengan. Therefore, it cannot maintain the amount of power in the end as the beginning

Answer (score 1):

As [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Vanishing_Rasengan) said, Boruto create a miniature of Rasengan then he inject the Rasengan with Wind release nature, so the it can be thrown.

> The user creates a miniature Rasengan, to the size of a big grape,
>   which is capable of being thrown due to the Wind Release nature
>   transformation that is applied. While gliding in the air, the sphere
>   disappears and hits the target.

About your question how Boruto was **able to vanish** the Rasengan, I think because it's so small, slowly vanishing while thrown but still hits the target because his Wind Release nature. But it's only my opinion of course.

Comment: The rasengan naturally is a Ball of Brute force, a Torrential Hurricane of chakra compressed to a small sphere that shreds everything it comes into contact with. I would bet that indeed it destabilizes enough that the visual effects disappear, but the raw force does not and continues traveling.

Comment: This isn't entirely right. Throughout most of the Anime, wind techniques have been mostly invisible ((Temari's and Baki's (the Sand Ninja's team leader) wind techniques)). Due to Boruto subconsciously applying wind nature to an under-developed Rasengan, it's more likely that while the raw chakra of the Rasengan wasn't stable enough to last the entire distance it was thrown, the wind nature chakra from it would have carried on and done that damage that we saw.  The only notable exception I can think of to invisible wind chakra is the Rasenshurkien.

Answer (score 0):

It is because he (unknowingly) puts a small amount of wind chakra in it and it somehow absorbs nature energy. That is how the Vanishing Rasengan works. It is still much of a mystery though.

Answer (score 0):

The vanishing rasengan is small and when it explodes it looks like it's only as big as a regular rasengan.But when Naruto creates a rasengan it explodes to a big hole therefore the regular rasengan is more powerful than the vanishing rasengan

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]! This is Q&A site, please take a [tour] for a while to make yourself familiar with the site. That aside, I'm not sure this post answers the question. It compares about regular and vanishing Rasengan, but no mention about how Boruto made the Rasengan vanish, nor the mechanic about Vanishing Rasengan.

Answer (score 0):

All of that is in fact wrong Borutos vanishing rasengan is not wind style at all. Sasuke states in the canon episode of the Momoshiki fight that Boruto unconsciously adds a lightning nature to his rasengan which is what allows it to move at such speeds and disappear. I assume it disappears because of the speed and lighting's tendency to disappear quickly. Well anyway Borutos rasengan is a lightning style.

Answer (score 0):

Sasuke said that boruto when infusing chakra to make a rasengan adds little amounts of  lightning style unintentionally which creates vanishing rasengan and the techniqur i presume isnt fully developed. The theory of the vanishing rasengan being wind style is wrong because Naruto has already made wind style rasengans which has a different effect